# How to install exact same module versions to production installation

Tags: magento2, composer, version, staging, production

I have tested all extensions and theme in staging installation and now I need to install the exact same versions of each module and theme to the production installation by using composer. What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the correct solution was the following:

1. Copy composer.json and composer.lock
2. Empty the vendor folder
3. Run composer install

Answer (score 0):

For your custom modules, you have to directly upload `app/code` directory

And for vendor modules, you have to copy module versions from staging `composer.json` and run composer install